# Java | Exception Handling | removing thrower stack

Tags: java, exception, completable-future

I have a requirement, where in the all the service implementation classes have a common way of handling the exception handling. The services uses the Java 8 Completable future.
Now the Completable future can recieve multiple exceptions and based on different type of exceptions, they have to be wrapped into new exceptions and thrown further from CompletableFuture.exceptionally() method.

Since the code for handling exceptions is common across all the services, I have extracted out the code in a utility class which is as follows:

```
 public static <T> Function<Throwable, ? extends T> getExceptionHandleFunction() {
    return throwable -> {

        Throwable throwableCause = throwable instanceof CompletionException ? throwable.getCause() : throwable;

        if (throwableCause instanceof PolicyViolation) {
            throw new ABCException("message", throwableCause);
        }

        if (!(throwableCause instanceof LLCaresTransportException)) {
            throw new DEFException("message", throwableCause);
        }

        throw (GHIException) throwableCause;

    };
}
```

Now the things works absolutely fine with the only problem that my exception stack in logs starts with this UtilityClass where this method is written.

I don't want my logs to show this unnecessary stack since it's not useful and doesn't show a real picture of where the exception is starting from.

Is there a way where in I can truncate the stack of this utility class or is there a graceful way to handle these kind of scenarios.
I tried Apache Commons ExceptionUtils, but they don't support this kind of use case.

Comment: You can override `fillInStackTrace` method of your Exception classes, for which you don't want to print stacktrace.

Comment: This seems like badly using the Function interface. Are you calling its apply method to raise the proper exception? Should you perhaps `throw getExceptionHandleFunction().apply(throwable);`? and make the Function just return a throwable object instead of throwing it?

Comment: @ernest_k Yep. This sounds good as well. The only intent to making everything put in a function was the throwing part was again common across different classes. But yes, this does make sense. However, the question is still open on how to make the stack of exceptions controllable in java.

Comment: @Saheb: Thanks but I don't want to loose the final exception class stack. All I want is stack not to have the utility class trace but from the caller of the utility method. Your solution will work but it will hide the final stack.

Comment: @piyushGoyal, please share the code where the exception is being logged/printed.

Comment: @ernest_k: I followed your solution since we was clean and was better more from design perpective that the throw should only be handled from the catch block of the try getting the exception and as per SOLID principle, the only responsibility of the method should be get me that exception. However, I am still looking out for the answer of my question. Is it even possible in java?

Comment: @piyushGoyal How are you seeing the class name? From the output of `exception.printStackTrace()`? Or are you somehow converting it to a string (such as by using `ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace`)? Otherwise, which version of Java are you using? (9 gives you additional tools)

Comment: Java 8. Currently the common utility method is just returning the type of exception. It's thrown explicitly from where it should be thrown so I dont have the problem of managing stacktrace. Havent explored java 9 yet.